# Is it possible to export view to Excel in specify format without using Apache POI?

Tags: excel, xpages

I read [this article](https://guedebyte.wordpress.com/2012/09/07/documents-and-spreadsheets-i/). The program (from website) allows the user to generate a customized Word document use Apache POI. I found the code from these [two](http://blog.texasswede.com/export-notes-view-to-excel-with-multi-value-fields/) [websites](http://www.botstation.com/code/view2excelweb.php) that can generate Excel file use agent, however the output is generate the view in Excel format only.

Is it possible to export view to Excel in specify format without use Apache POI?
Instead of using Apache POI, is it possible to write code in agent to generate a customized Excel file?

Comment: any particular reason why you don't want to use POI? With POI4XPages it is easily usable --> http://poi4xpages.openntf.org/

Comment: @MichaelRuhnau, thank you for your reply. I know Apache POI is suitable to my current project and I check Domino Designer I am using can fulfill the installation requirements. However my colleagues, who working on the same project are not able to use POI at the moment because of the designer version. And our user also are not able to use POI at the moment. Therefore, in order to unify the project, we have to find out another way to achieve the goal without POI. Again, I believe POI can let our team use less time to build the project and I hope I can use POI in the future. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No and Yes. You deal with Java on XPages. You could reinvent the wheel and write all was POI does yourself, so yes you could.

You also could output a HTML table but send a header of application\vnd-excel to get the table automatically opened in Excel (but no formula here)

What would stop you from using POI?

Comment: Plus bear in mind that an HTML table with a header throws a security warning to the user since Internet Explorer 9, because it's not a valid Excel file, it's just HTML spoofing an Excel spreadsheet.
If you've written a LotusScript agent to create a spreadsheet, POI is straightforward. But if you're calling it from XPages, don't call an agent. Use SSJS (or Java, if preferring that route).

Comment: @stwissel,  thank you for your reply. I know Apache POI is suitable to my current project and I check Domino Designer I am using can fulfill the installation requirements. However my colleagues, who working on the same project are not able to use POI at the moment because of the designer version. And our user also are not able to use POI at the moment. Therefore, in order to unify the project, we have to find out another way to achieve the goal without POI. Again, I believe POI can let our team use less time to build the project and I hope I can use POI in the future. Thank you.

Comment: The trick with the mime type most likely won't work in XPiNC. On a Domino server since 8.5.0 you can use POI. So you might need to add poi manually to your project (using the navigator and the webcontent folder). What else would stop you?

Comment: @PaulStephenWithers, thank you for your reply. I will take note for your advice. Thank you.

Comment: @stwissel, thanks your reply. May I ask a question please? In this website https://my.webgate.biz/poi/documentation.nsf/viewdoc.xsp?docid=installguide  , it mention the version should be 8.5.3. So if I add the poi manually to the project, will my colleagues can use it? (my colleagues currently is using 8.5.2FP4) Thank you.

Comment: Unless your license prohibits you from upgrading, your colleagues should upgrade. The big difference: in 853 you have Java design elements. if you deploy it using the webFolder approach, you could do that in 852. Anyway: server should be on 901FP4++ to make sure TLS1.2 is available for security